# not able to make a DataFrame with yFinance JSON values

Tags: python, api, dataframe, yfinance

I am trying to make a data frame with some of the information I received from yFinance.info. I have a list of s&p 500 stock symbols, and I made a for loop using stocks' symbols to retrieve data

```
for sym in symbol:
    x=yf.Ticker(sym)
    sector.append(x.info['forwardPE'])
```

However, every time I run it, it runs for a very long time and returns this error.

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-13-c87646d48ecd> in <module>
     12 for sym in symbol:
     13     x=yf.Ticker(sym)
---> 14     sector.append(x.info['forwardPE'])
     15 

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/yfinance/ticker.py in info(self)
    136     @property
    137     def info(self):
--> 138         return self.get_info()
    139 
    140     @property

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/yfinance/base.py in get_info(self, proxy, as_dict, *args, **kwargs)
    444 
    445     def get_info(self, proxy=None, as_dict=False, *args, **kwargs):
--> 446         self._get_fundamentals(proxy)
    447         data = self._info
    448         if as_dict:

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/yfinance/base.py in _get_fundamentals(self, kind, proxy)
    283         # holders
    284         url = "{}/{}/holders".format(self._scrape_url, self.ticker)
--> 285         holders = _pd.read_html(url)
    286 
    287         if len(holders)>=3:

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/io/html.py in read_html(io, match, flavor, header, index_col, skiprows, attrs, parse_dates, thousands, encoding, decimal, converters, na_values, keep_default_na, displayed_only)
   1098         na_values=na_values,
   1099         keep_default_na=keep_default_na,
-> 1100         displayed_only=displayed_only,
   1101     )

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/io/html.py in _parse(flavor, io, match, attrs, encoding, displayed_only, **kwargs)
    913             break
    914     else:
--> 915         raise retained
    916 
    917     ret = []

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/io/html.py in _parse(flavor, io, match, attrs, encoding, displayed_only, **kwargs)
    893 
    894         try:
--> 895             tables = p.parse_tables()
    896         except ValueError as caught:
    897             # if `io` is an io-like object, check if it's seekable

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/io/html.py in parse_tables(self)
    211         list of parsed (header, body, footer) tuples from tables.
    212         """
--> 213         tables = self._parse_tables(self._build_doc(), self.match, self.attrs)
    214         return (self._parse_thead_tbody_tfoot(table) for table in tables)
    215 

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/io/html.py in _parse_tables(self, doc, match, attrs)
    543 
    544         if not tables:
--> 545             raise ValueError("No tables found")
    546 
    547         result = []

ValueError: No tables found
```

When I do it without the append (eg."x.info['forwardPE']), it runs fine and return values one by one. Can anybody please help me with how I could fix this problem? Sorry for the horrible summarization and thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could put the line in a `try` block and `except` the errors to see which symbols aren't working properly. Since you have 500 tickers to go through, you may encounter more than one exception so I'd recommend using a broad `except Exception` statement and using `traceback` (optional) to get more info on the error

```
import traceback
import yfinance as yf

symbol = ['TSLA', 'F', 'MNQ', 'MMM']
sector = []

for sym in symbol:

    try:
        x = yf.Ticker(sym)
        sector.append(x.info['forwardPE'])

    except Exception as error:
        print()
        print(f'{error} for symbol {sym}')
        print(traceback.format_exc())


print(sector)
```

Comment: Hello, thank you so much! I added sector.append("null") under except statement so I could see which stocks did not have values.

Comment: You're welcome! I'd recommend `sector.append("null " + sym)` otherwise your `sector` list will only say `"null"` where there's missing values and you wouldn't really know which stock it is without also adding `sym`